# I can't figure out what is wrong with this function?

Tags: python, function, operation

This is what it should return

Returns True if all items are truthy.

```
Examples:
>>> all_true([1, True, 'oregonstate'])
True
>>> all_true([0, 1, 2])
False
"""
```

This is what I have written

```
def all_true(items):
    for i in items:
        if i == True:
            return True
        else:
          return False
    pass
```

Not sure why it is not working, can someone help?

Comment: Your function only check for the first value of the collection and returns

Comment: You return on the first true thing. So this is "any" not "all".

Answer (score 4):

Your function just returns the truthiness of the first item in the list, since it always returns on the first iteration.

You want to do something like this:

```
def all_true(items):
    for i in items:
        if not i:
            return False
    return True
```

Note that this `all_true` function already exists in Python. It is the the built-in `all` function.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems. First, you are returning on the first `True` thing. In fact, you are returning either `True` or `False` on the first thing, regardless. Since you return on both the `if` and its `else` clauses, the loop will always return on the first iteration. A bit more subtle, but if there aren't any values in the list, it will return `None`.

Second, if you want "truthy", don't compare specifically to `True`. `foo == True` is `False`. Instead, just let the `if` do the boolean test

```
def all_true(items):
    for i in items:
        if not i:
            return False
    return True
```

`all` and `any` are builtin functions that do the same thing. It would generally be preferable to use them.

Answer (score 0):

"All items are truthy" is logically equivalent to "no items are falsy."

```
def all_true(items):
    for i in items:
        if not i:
            return False
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Because 0 is falsy. Also there's no need to implement your own function for that, use Python's built–in `all()` function instead!